# Proper way of testing whether a Docker Compose configuration will start up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Basically, something like `nginx -t`, where nothing can break.

I have a NGINX proxy running in Docker which is networked to several other Docker networks (web applications). Sometimes I need to restart the proxy, but if one of the connected networks is no longer accessible to the proxy the proxy fails to restart even if it was able to run fine before the restart.

Is there a way to restart Docker containers without risking downtime caused 
by this?

Comment: What type of network are you testing to see if it's up? A regular Docker Bridge network?

Comment: Yes, using static IP addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dry-run feature for docker-compose is an [open feature request](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1203) for the time being.

Comment: Even found a similar question (and answer (:): https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/9306

Answer (score 3):

I think a better approach is to make Nginx configuration more robust:

Ref: [make nginx ignore site config when its upstream cannot be reached](https://serverfault.com/questions/700894/make-nginx-ignore-site-config-when-its-upstream-cannot-be-reached/701864#701864)

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty because it was the most helpful even though it technically wasn't the answer for the Docker question specifically :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not assign tasks (that belongs to the nginx) to docker, more specifically fix it in your `nginx.conf`!

The right way to resolve your "issue" is using [upstreams](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).